# Applescript to sort files into folder based on British financial year

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm looking for way to move files based on UK financial year (runs from 6th April -5th April).
Files are named in pattern as

```
2014-08-26_Asda_lunch.pdf
2016-03-20_Tesco_sationary.pdf
```

The File needs to be moved to folders which are named, and so on

```
FY 2014-15
FY 2015-16
```

Just wondering if applescript/ shell script or automator action would help to achieve this. Also interface with hazel wud be even better

Thanks in advance
I have tried to modify the script

My first aim is get month right, then wud try dates;
the Output for Script
File 2019-07-26_Tesco_stationary -> FY 2020 ( expected FY 2019-20)
File 2019-03-15_Sainsbury -> FY 2019 ( expected FY 2018-19)
Please advise, also any pointers to add date in sorting wud be helpful
Thank you

```
set savedDelimiters to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"-"}

tell application "Finder"
   set filename to name of theFile
end tell

set expenseYear to (first text item of filename) as number
set expenseMonth to (second text item of filename) as number
set expenseDate to (third text item of filename) as number

-- Get the last two characters of the Year
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to savedDelimiters
set lastTwoCharactersOfYear to (characters 3 thru 4 of (expenseYear as text))
set RoundedExpYear to (lastTwoCharactersOfYear as text) as number


if expenseMonth ≥ 4 then
   set LongString to expenseYear
   set ShortString to RoundedExpYear + 1
else
   set LongString to expenseYear - 1
   set ShortString to RoundedExpYear
end if


set returnText to "FY" & " " & LongString & "-" & ShortString
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to parse dates but since your format is always the same (yyyy-mm-dd_xxxx) I used the easiest way. In script below the handler GetFY returns directly the format you're looking for "FY YYYY-YYYY" when you give parameter your file name:

```
set Fname to "2014-03-05_xxxx" -- value to test
set myfolder to GetFy(Fname)
log "myfolder=" & myfolder

on GetFy(Fname) -- return FY-(FY+1) based on Fname as YYYY-MM-DD_xxxxxx
    set myear to (text 1 thru 4 of Fname) as integer
    set mmonth to (text 6 thru 7 of Fname) as integer
    set mday to (text 9 thru 10 of Fname) as integer
    if mmonth < 4 then set Fy to myear - 1
    if mmonth = 4 then set Fy to myear - ((mday ≤ 5) as integer)
    if mmonth > 4 then set Fy to myear
    return "FY " & Fy & "-" & (Fy + 1)
end GetFy
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, Tired to modify the script [ function hazelMatchFile(theFile, inputAttributes)

{ 
 set myfolder to GetFy(theFile)
 log "myfolder=" & myfolder
    on GetFy(theFile) -- return FY-(FY+1) based on theFile as YYYY-MM-DD_xxxxxx

    .....end GetFy
}]..gives error on line 5:Unexpected identifier 'myfolder'

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand your modification and where you get error. The script I made does not give me any error. The output of GetFy is not a folder, but a string like "FY 2019-2020". Up to you to assign this name to a folder somewhere else in your script. The parameter to be sent to GetFy is also a string like the file name, but not a file.

Comment: Thank you @pbell, just a novice with these, was trying to use it with Hazel, hence all the mess up. Apologies I do not know how to use your remarkable script :(   I guessed in the script I posted, the issue was delimter, and realised u cant specifiy 2 delimters. I extracted the date string with "_" demiter, then reset the delimiter to "-" to get expense year/month & date. and then setting delimiters to default. And it worked. Ever so grateful for your time & help

Comment: I understand now, wht you suggested, it works perfectly !, now I know how to use the code. Thank you for ur help Best wishes